# When is quadratic form positive-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

From the definition of the quadratic form follows that for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n,\; c \in \mathbb{R}$ holds $ q(cx) = c^2q(x) $ ( I understand this)

From this you can to prove that (I don't know how), for example, $q$ is positively definite if and only if
$ q(x)>0 $ for each $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $ satisfying $ \| x \|=1 $.

Does anyone please have idea how to prove that or at least how to start?

Comment: You have total freedom to choose $c$. Choose your $c$ in such a way that it is related to $x$.

Comment: @311411 What if I choose $c=\frac{1}{\| x \|}$ ? I still need a little advice

Comment: @david_svec With that choice of $c$ let $y=cx=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ then $\|y\|=1$ so $q(x)=\frac{1}{c^2}q(y) \gt 0$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you, I understand this now.